# Does the EU frequently review their members to see if they consistently meet the initial criteria?

Tags: european-union, europe, greece, euro

Does the EU conduct frequent reviews on the economic and political condition of their members to stay? If a current member of the European Union drastically changes economically or politically, and no longer meets the initial criteria to be an EU member, are they ousted?

Comment: related question: [Can a state be forced to leave the European Union?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9736/can-a-state-be-forced-to-leave-the-european-union)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one has ever been ousted from the EU.  Several of the [Maastricht criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_convergence_criteria) only apply to countries that have not yet joined the common currency.  For example, inflation, exchange rate stability, and long term interest rates are the responsibility of the EU central bank after convergence.  In 2014, fifteen of twenty-seven countries missed the criterion for debt as a percentage of GDP:

[image: Graph of European country debt as a percentage of GDP]

Source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fiscal_Compliance_2014-debt.png

While people have discussed the possibility of Greece or the UK leaving, I've never heard anyone argue that Germany or France should be kicked out.  The UK discussion that I have seen has been about the UK leaving voluntarily.  Both sides have discussed the possibility of Greece leaving.

The [Stability and Growth Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_and_Growth_Pact) is supposed to regulate compliance with the fiscal criteria, but the non-compliance of Germany and France has led to it being imperfectly applied.  It is supposed to invoke penalties in the case of non-compliance but hasn't in many cases and was explicitly weakened in 2005.